# react native appium with webdriver crash

Tags: react-native, testing, appium, chai

I follow this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/test-automation-in-react-native-ac9ac2330ab9) to set up testing in my app with appium and webdriver.

my wdio.config is

```
    exports.config = {
  services: ['appium'],
  port: 4723,
  runner: 'local',
  specs: ['./tests/*.js'],
  capabilities: [
    {
      maxInstances: 1,
      browserName: '',
      appiumVersion: '1.20.2',
      platformName: 'Android',
      platformVersion: '11',
      deviceName: '99211FFAZ00843',
      app: './apps/app-dev-debug.apk',
      automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
    },
  ],

  logLevel: 'trace',
  bail: 0,
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  framework: 'mocha',
  reporters: ['spec'],
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 60000,
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "automationTests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "wdio.conf.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.0.5",
    "chai": "^4.3.0",
    "wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
    "webdriverio": "^7.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.0.5",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.0.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.0.4",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.0.5",
    "chromedriver": "^88.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I have tests folder with test file App.test.js

```
const TestsIds = require('../../../src/assets/test_ids');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Simple App testing', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {});

  it('Valid Login Test', () => {
    const skipButton = $(`~$view-app-id`).waitForDisplayed(3000, false);
    skipButton.click();
  });
});
```

I got this error

```
 ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0] 2021-02-18T12:34:11.688Z ERROR webdriver: unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
    at Object.getErrorFromResponseBody (/Users/XXX/Desktop/projects/XXXXX/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:189:12)
    at WebDriverRequest._request (//Users/XXX/Desktop/projects/XXXXX/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:168:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[0-0] 2021-02-18T12:34:11.690Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
    at Object.startWebDriverSession (//Users/XXX/Desktop/projects/XXXXX/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2021-02-18T12:34:11.810Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
[0-0] FAILED in undefined - /tests/App.test.js
2021-02-18T12:34:11.811Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:01
```

in addition I get error in the app.test.js

```
skipButton.click() is not function
```

Comment: Hi, do you have logs from [Appium] server prompt ?

Comment: no, just what I added

Comment: ok found that this tutorial is missing path of appium server url, I will rewrite config file, and don't forget to restart appium server

Comment: Hello, did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Could you share some reproducible code?

Comment: I share all I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find configurations here : https://webdriver.io/docs/options/#webdriver-options

you need to change configuration file like this :

```
exports.config = {
  services: ['appium'],
  port: 4723,

  // PATH is important for appium local server :
  path: '/wd/hub/',
  
  runner: 'local',
  specs: ['./tests/*.js'],
  capabilities: [
    {
      maxInstances: 1,
      browserName: '',
      appiumVersion: '1.20.2',
      platformName: 'Android',
      platformVersion: '11',
      deviceName: '99211FFAZ00843',
      app: './apps/app-dev-debug.apk',
      automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
    },
  ],

  logLevel: 'trace',
  bail: 0,
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  framework: 'mocha',
  reporters: ['spec'],
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 60000,
  },
};
```

In order to expect something from your test, try this update for your App.test.js :

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const TestsIds = require('../../../src/assets/test_ids');

const delay = millis => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => resolve(), millis)
});


describe('Simple App testing', () => {
    
  // Adding time (20sec) to make sure the app is load prior to test is run
  before(async () => {
    await delay(20000);
  });

  it('My first test', async => {
    // here we uss waitForDisplayed with default settings from wdio.conf.js
    $('~[YourAccessibilityLabel]').waitForDisplayed();

    // make sure [YourAccessibilityLabel] exist with simple expect :
    let isHome = $('~[YourAccessibilityLabel]').isExisting();
    expect(isHome).to.equal(true);

    // then click to continue your app testing
    skipButton.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: Error: Cannot find module 'appium'. in addition it looks like it open the app and after 2 sec it close it but test success.  what syntax to use? should I pause the driver?

Comment: Hi, for the first error : try to rerun Yarn install or NPM install command on your test folder, and then I updated my answer to show you how to create a simple expect test, don't forget to change [YourAccessibilityLabel] :)

Comment: Hi, I run npm install in test folder and still get the error @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "appium" as NPM package

Comment: Ok that's not an error, If you got something like: DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "appium" as NPM package, your error was fix (Error: Cannot find module 'appium'). This is a simple log to inform you that Appium service is going to start